# How to sort a dictionary of lists based on its numeric values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary as the following data structure:

```
d = {'TRANSFERRED': [2281, 1031, 1775, 867, 1242],
     'CLOSED':      [239, 269, 645, 540, 388], 
     'DEFERRED':    [89, 5, 68, 48, 37],
     'OPEN':        [3, 0, 2, 1, 0],
     'IN PROGRESS': [0, 2, 4, 0, 5],
     'QUEUED':      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

The dictionary contains lists with numeric values and I would like to order them based on the sum of its numeric values, something like this:

```
d = {'TRANSFERRED': [2281, 1031, 1775, 867, 1242], # sum gives 7196 
     'CLOSED':      [239, 269, 645, 540, 388], # sum gives 2081
     'DEFERRED':    [89, 5, 68, 48, 37], # sum gives 247
     'IN PROGRESS': [0, 2, 4, 0, 5], # sum gives 11
     'OPEN':        [3, 0, 2, 1, 0], # sum gives 6 
     'QUEUED':      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]} # sum gives 0
```

As you see, the new dictionary is sorted based on the sum of the numeric values of each list from the highest to the lowest. I have been using the following trick to order dictionaries with lists that contain single items such as:

```
d2 = {'TRANSFERRED': [-2281],
      'CLOSED':      [239], 
      'DEFERRED':    [489],
      'OPEN':        [34],
      'IN PROGRESS': [0],
      'QUEUED':      [-10]}

sorted(d2.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

I want to replicate this same result but based on the sum of values of each list in the dictionary. How can I reach this goal? Please, feel free to use the following link [repl.it - sort dictionary based on its values of lists](https://repl.it/repls/NauticalPrimaryKittiwake). Feedback or comments to improve this question are welcome.

Comment: `sorted(d2.items(), key=lambda x: sum(x[1]), reverse=True)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make one change to your current approach - return a `sum` from the `key` function:

```
sorted(d2.items(), key=lambda x: sum(x[1]), reverse=True)
#                                ^change ^
```

Demo:

```
In [2]: sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: sum(item[1]), reverse=True)
Out[2]: 
[('TRANSFERRED', [2281, 1031, 1775, 867, 1242]),
 ('CLOSED', [239, 269, 645, 540, 388]),
 ('DEFERRED', [89, 5, 68, 48, 37]),
 ('IN PROGRESS', [0, 2, 4, 0, 5]),
 ('OPEN', [3, 0, 2, 1, 0]),
 ('QUEUED', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0])]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#you can solve this problem using sort and sum functions.


# original list.
d = {'TRANSFERRED': [2281, 1031, 1775, 867, 1242],
     'CLOSED':      [239, 269, 645, 540, 388], 
     'DEFERRED':    [89, 5, 68, 48, 37],
     'OPEN':        [3, 0, 2, 1, 0],
     'IN PROGRESS': [0, 2, 4, 0, 5],
     'QUEUED':      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}


#function to calculate the sum of a list
def list_sum(t):
  return sum(t[1])

# we can not sort dict. directly so we have to make the dict into list of tuples
# were key will be the first element and value will be the second element.
# will become 'TRANSFERRED': [2281, 1031, 1775, 867, 1242]
# ( 'TRANSFERRED', [2281, 1031, 1775, 867, 1242])
# t0 = 'TRANSFERRED'
# t1 = [2281, 1031, 1775, 867, 1242]


# sorted function will sorted the list of tuples based on the result
# generated by the list_sum function 

result = sorted(d.items(),key=list_sum,reverse=True)
print(result)
```